# Error: Connection activation failed: No suitable device found for this connection

Tags: networking, fedora, networkmanager

glad to be on these forums!

I searched around a bit on the forums, but couldn't find a good pre-existing case for this that might resolve anything.

The error just happened out of nowhere after a boot-up, but I do have an "enp" type wireless device name listed at "DEVICE=" in a file named "ifcfg-[my own device name]" which can be a problem if not the case, so what happened here?

When I run "systemctl restart network", I get: "job for network.service failed because the control process exited with error code".

1) Restarting anything does no good for anything.
2) I haven't tried re-installing anything - yet.
3) "ip add flush [device name]" does nothing, says my device doesn't exist.
4) Pinging 127.0.0.1 gives response.

At one point, I got this message too: "failed to start lsb bring up/down networking"

What suddenly happened here?

I'm on a fedora30.

Thx for taking the time to read this.

RX

Answer (score 0):

Check that the network script doesn't have a mismatching `HWADDR=<xx:xx>` and actual mac address. Also make sure the network script doesn't have both of the `HWADDR=<xx:xx>` and `MACADDR=<xx:xx>`lines at the same time